# Creating table with dates as rows from table with start date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-administration

Sorry for complicated title, but here is my problem:

I have a table that has data about production of factories. Each factory has two products and columns about production losses for each product. Factory also has status where 1 means everything is OK and factory is at full production(GrossProduction), 2 restriction in production and 3 when factory is in maintenance.

```
ID | FactoryID | Status |    StartTimestamp     | ProductionLoss1 | ProductionLoss2 | GrossProduction1 | GrossProction2
1  |    100    |   1    |2015-01-05 12:15:00.000|        0        |        0        |        100       |        150       
2  |    200    |   1    |2015-01-03 12:15:00.000|        0        |        0        |        40        |        90 
3  |    100    |   2    |2015-01-29 10:00:00.000|        80       |        100      |        100       |        150    
4  |    100    |   1    |2015-02-03 08:00:00.000|        0        |        0        |        100       |        150   
5  |    200    |   2    |2015-02-05 08:00:00.000|        100      |        150      |        40        |        90  
6  |    200    |   3    |2015-02-06 00:00:00.000|        100      |        150      |        40        |        90  
.
.
.
```

I have to change this table into another table where every date has own row and corresponding productions and lost productions for all products.

Production is calculated:

Production for day = 24 * GrossProction - LostProduction - LostProductionDueMaintenance

LostProduction = If status==2 Then 24 * ProductionLoss

LostProductionDueMaintenance = If status == 3 Then 24 * ProductionLoss

Output table should be like this:

All factories should have row for each date and corresponding production quantities.

```
DateKey    |FactoryID| Production1 | ProductionLoss2 | LostProduction1 | LostProduction2 | LostProductionDueMaintenance1 | LostProductionDueMaintenance2
2015-01-05 |   100   |     2400    |      3600       |        0        |        0        |             0                 |            0
2015-01-05 |   200   |     960     |      2160       |        0        |        0        |             0                 |            0
.
.
.
2015-01-29 |   100   |     1280    |      2200       |       1120      |      1400       |             0                 |            0
.
.
.
2015-02-06 |   200   |     0       |       0         |       0         |        0        |             960               |            2160
```

I need to make SQL code to generate this table from above table in Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I have a date dimension to help with calculations.
I think it is needed to loop dates and all production units and all possible statuses but I'm quite lost in what to do.

If someone could give me a little help how to proceed it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement. To get to 2015-01-05 from 2015-01-05 12:15:00.000, you can use the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) statement. There's probably no need for a loop.